# IntelliJ doesn't display... at all

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I have a bug which is completely over the planet. IntellIJ doesn't display. It's on, yet doesn't display.

It worked well before, last thing I did was re-setting up new dependencies on my code and (nothing to do with that) re-setting SDK for other reasons, both of which shouldn't be linked to display properties.

As you can see it's working, I see the pop up windows:
[image: As you can see it's working, I see the pop up windows]

But doesn't display:
[image: But doesn't display]

Yet I can see IntelliJ windows with <kbd>Shift + Tab</kbd>:
[image: yet I can see IntelliJ windows with shift+tab]

and yes, my screen doesn't duplicate, so it's not hidden in another dimension or something
[image: and yes, my screen doesn't duplicate, so it's not hidden in another dimension or something]

I tried:

- restart computer
- uninstall install IntelliJ
- uninstall install IntelliJ without previous parameters
- try other JetBrains software, like DataGrip, it works and displays well
- call a homeopathic doctor

Unsuccessfully. So I knee and await before your judgement of this critical situation.

Comment: check if any process is already running in Task Manager, and if anything is running stop it. also remove all configured files as well from computer.

Comment: Indeed I can use Eclipse but that's not the point. I would like to figure this out. It worked before and as far as I know, it should work here.

Comment: I tried task manager and configured files were remove at the last uninstall process. No change unfortunately. Yet I see it running in the task manager windows (obviously since I see it with alt+tab)

Comment: What do you mean "IntelliJ doesn't display"? What exactly are you trying to do? Can you give a screenshot?

Comment: Screenshots are in the hyperlinks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I have this exact same behavior happen to me when I use IntelliJ at work and then go home and try to use it via Remote Desktop.  It's very strange (regardless of which monitor I leave it on at work when I leave).

If I hover over it in the task bar and then hover over the thumbnail for the running app, I can right click and tell it to maximize and it magically comes back into focus.  Sometimes I have to tell it to restore and then to maximize before this works.

Occasionally even this doesn't work and I have to close it, re-open, and do the same.  It makes no sense, so I understand your frustration.

Comment: Thank you, I see what you mean, it doesn't work for me, I tried and retried (see first hyperlink in my first message)

Comment: looks like known bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153291.  workaround: 1) Shift-Right mouse Click on pinned to tasks bar Idea Icon 2) Maximize (Gets windows to recalculate the bounds

Answer (score 8):

It works

As John Humphreys - w00te mentionned, click right over the thumbnail (I insist: the thumbnail ! Not the taskbar icon) and then select maximize and voilà.

Bon appétit.

Thanks for your contribution and I hope it will help some people in need here.

Comment: Awesome :) please accept the answer so it shows as closed.

Comment: Awesome, It really helps

Answer (score 5):

Keep pressing ´ALT + Tab´ until IntelliJ window selected.
Then press ´ALT + Space´ to display hidden window's context menu then select ´Maximize´.

[image: Window's context menu]

Answer (score 4):

I have had this issue when I have moved from a dual monitor setup to a single monitor setup or a different dual monitor set up.  The issue here that intellij window seems to save and use the coordinates of the last dual window setup to render the window. It doesn't matter you restart your computer, it will always try and render to that position, even if that position is not visible on the new monitor set up.  On windows there is an easy way to fix this issue. Go to your display setting and flip the order of the windows.  The intellij window should now be visible.  you can drag the window to the your other monitor and re-arrange the windows back to the order you had previously.  After that, you can place the intellij window wherever you want.

Answer (score 2):

On mac, select the app from the app tray so that the menu for it appears up top. Then on the menu up top, go to Windows->Zoom and it should expand to fill the viewport.

From there you can drag it down to size and reposition.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I noticed there is a 1 pixel thick gray line on my screen, turns out that was the IDEA window and I could resize upon hovering that line. Needless to say it wasn't me shrinking it.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same behavior, It happens to me when I connect a monitor in extended mode and move the intellij window to the monitor, then disconnect without moving it back. No other solution other than to connect to monitor again and bring it back to the original window for me works.